# How to change the font in VS Code's 'Explorer' window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the font in the Explorer window (the panel on the left that shows files in your working directory, NOT the editor where you write code)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change vscode sidebar font family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046039/how-can-i-change-vscode-sidebar-font-family)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) providing the requested feature in vscode:

- Follow instructions in the link
- Add css code on `.monaco-panel-view` in `.vscodestyles.css` file.

For instance:

```css
.monaco-panel-view:not(h3) {
  font-family: "SF Pro Display" !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  font-size: 13.3px !important;
}
```

Note: for further editing, use <kbd>f1</kbd> -> Toggle developer tools to find out which classes to edit. Use elemnt selector for finding element in the css.