# Change background and font in "Problems" panel in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the most recent copy of VSCode.
I'd like to change the background color and font on the "Problems" panel in the terminal window.

I have used theJSON settings to set up the background on the terminal window itself but can't seem to find a setup for the problems panel.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `panel` properties to change the Problems panel.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "panel.background": "#0b698f",
  "panel.border": "#ff510060"
}
```

But it will change the background for all the panel items, like Terminal, Problems, Debug Console, etc.

You can override that setting for the Terminal only:

`"terminal.background": "#ff0000",`

It would appear that the Problems panel fontFamily cannot be independently set as I see only these two panel fontFamily properties:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily"
"debug.console.fontFamily"
```

You might be able to figure out how to do it with the [Custom CSS and JS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css).  See, for example, [How to change the font in VS Code's 'Explorer' window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202063/how-to-change-the-font-in-vs-codes-explorer-window)

Maybe it is `<div class="composite panel markers-panel"`

Comment: The panel.background does do all four panels but that's fine.Thanks