# How to change the color of the title bar of console on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the color of the title bar of the terminal?
If not, how do I add a border to the terminal so that I can see a line separation between the editor and the integrated terminal?
[image of the titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yls1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Command Palette using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and run it. This should open `settings.json` in a new window.

   [image: Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)]
3. Add the following new property into your `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "[YOUR_COLOR_SCHEME_NAME]": {
        "panel.background": "#ff0000"  // Replace #ff0000 with your color of choice
     }
   },
   ```

   Replace `YOUR_COLOR_SCHEME_NAME` with the name of the color scheme you are using. For example, if my color scheme is called "Monokai Pro", I write `"[Monokai Pro]": {` in the second line.

Comment: I use theme "Dark (Visual Studio)", but the setting `"[Dark (Visual Studio)]": {` seems not to work.   I also tried using "Monokai", and that works OK.  is anything special needed ?

Comment: You can directly do `"workbench.colorCustomizations": { "panel.background": "#ff0000" }`

Answer (score 8):

See my answer here: [Change background and font in "Problems" panel in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581623/change-background-and-font-in-problems-panel-in-vscode)

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "panel.background": "#0b698f",
   "panel.border": "#ff510060"
}
```

There is currently no way to separately color just the "title bar" area of the Panel.  You would have to color the entire Panel to change the color of that area.  Here are the Panel colors that can be changed: [Panel theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#panel-colors).  `panelTitle` might be of interest to you.