# Can we change the font of the vscode file and directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: This thing i want to change fonts]

Solution to this if we can change or not. If we can change then, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the font in VS Code's 'Explorer' window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202063/how-to-change-the-font-in-vs-codes-explorer-window)

Answer (score 0):

So far you can't do this by default, but there are several extensions that allow for further customization. I use [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui). After the installation, add the following to your user settings:

```json
{
  "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".explorer-item a": {
      "font-family": "'Victor Mono', monospace !important"
    }
  }
}
```

Replace the font-family with the font you want to use